# php code insde html select form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am writing a simple PHP script inside a HTML form tag and running it using the Apache  server but it's not working. When I check the HTML code inside the browser it automatically falls under `<!--   (php code)  -->`  tag. Please explain
why and what is the fix?

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <select name="day">
        <option value="">day</option>
           <?php
               for($i = 1;$i <= 31; $i++){
               print "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";}
            ?>
     </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

seriously hoping its not a stupid mistake -__- if yes do let me know -_-
The above code is  part of a small html file

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `automatically falls under tag`?

Comment: What is the extension of the file you try to run on the apache server. Also I wonder if the code you included with your answer is the content of the file that you try to run on the apache server or is it the source code of the webpage?

Comment: oops  my bad it falls under the html comment tag <!-- (php code)--> and that little code is not allowed in the above definition .. wwtt

Answer (score 1):

I run the same code you posted. There is not any error it executes properly showing a day dropdown. I saved my file with .php extension. i think you saved your file in .html format. If yes please save it in .php extension.

Comment: The writer of the book saves it in a html document -__-

Comment: but it will run only  in .php file not in .html file

Comment: Then you better try another book.

Comment: @Syndicate A server can be configured to parse .html as PHP, however that's not common. It's far more common to simply give the page a .php extension.

Comment: i did some digging around and came to find the same answer thank you @j08691

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
echo "something";
```

Or:

```
print ("something");
```

It should work then!